# Ao clicar no botão faz duas requisições ajax, como evitar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quando eu clico no botão "Contratar" ele faz duas requisições no servidor de uma vez só, como eu posso evitar isso?

```
<button type="button" class="pagar" id="10.00">Contratar</button>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).on('click', ".pagar", function () {
    preco = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: path + 'Usuario/efetuarPagamento',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {preco: preco},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

        }, error: function () {
            console.log(erro, er);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Só vai haver duas requisições se houver dois cliques ou se tiver entrando duas vezes no callback do evento. É isso que está acontecendo?

Comment: Não existe dois cliques, eu apenas clico uma vez e ele faz duas requisições, parece que ele está entrando duas vezes na callback

Comment: O elemento com a classe `.pagar` é criado dinâmicamente? Porque só se for justifica o uso de `on` no documento..

Comment: Sim, eu estou criando vários botões que vão fazer a mesma coisa. Eu dei console.log(this); e ele me retorna o botão duas vezes..

Comment: Não testado, mas experimente ver se não problema de propagação. https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque seu código em uma função :

```
function teste(e){
 preco = $(e).attr('id');
 $.ajax({
    url: path + 'Usuario/efetuarPagamento',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {preco: preco},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

    }, error: function () {
        console.log(erro, er);
    }
 });
}
```

E sempre que criar um novo botão você adicionar o attr ou diretamente na criação assim :

`<input onclick="teste(this)">`

ou

```
$('input').attr('onclick','teste(this)');
```

Comment: Isso vai funcionar se o elemento não foi gerado dinâmicamente.

Comment: Isso não funciona no meu caso, estou gerando vários botões que vão fazer a mesma coisa. (Obs: ja testei)

Comment: Alterei a resposta, veja se funciona.

Comment: Deu certo haha, muito obrigado!